# MySQL case statement with two tables

Tags: sql, mysql, null

How can I improve the following working SQL statement for better performance and consistency?

```
SELECT if(roll is null,0,roll) as roll, 
       if(cpapername is null,0,cpapername) as compulsory,
       if(corepapername is null,0,corepapername) as Core, 
       if(e1papername is null,0,e1papername) as Elective1,
       if(e2papername is null,0,e2papername) as Elective2
       FROM(
       Select student.univ_roll as roll, student.name as name, student.rollno as rollno, 
       (CASE WHEN student.compulsory = paper.subject
         THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS cpapername,
       (CASE WHEN student.core= paper.subject
         THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS corepapername,
       (CASE WHEN student.elective_I= paper.subject
         THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS e1papername,
       (CASE WHEN student.elective_II= paper.subject
         THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS e2papername
        FROM student, paper WHERE student.semester='First' 
        AND student.batch='2014' AND student.class='BSc' 
        AND student.semester=paper.semester AND student.batch=paper.batch 
        AND student.class=paper.class  AND student.regd='1')r
```

Any suggestions and alternative solution are greatly welcome and appreciated as I am looking for better ways to code.

Comment: Are there `NOT NULL` constraints on columns `paper.name`, `paper.subject`, `student.compulsory`, `student.core`, etc.?

Comment: In my next version, instead of `if()`, I used `group_concat` which eliminates null cells and outputs single row.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` will probably produce the wrong output if you add a `GROUP BY` clause to your SQL.  I would avoid this use of `GROUP_CONCAT` for that reason.  You're really not using it as intended but for a side effect of its behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify `if(col is null,0,col)` as `ifnull(col, 0)`.

The SQL keywords are inconsistently formatted.
Sometimes you write `SELECT`, other times as `Select`.
I suggest to stick to all caps always.
The same goes for `if` (and `ifnull`) and `as` too.
It's easier to read the code when the writing is consistent.

The last line of your script is very long,
and it's difficult to read when I have to scroll to the right and the left part goes out of sight.
I suggest to add a few line breaks in there to make the code fit within one horizontal window. *(I see you updated your original post, now it's good.)*

It would be better to indent the sub-query more, and to put the closing `)` on a new line to make it more visible. Something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(roll, 0) AS roll, 
       IFNULL(cpapername, 0) AS compulsory,
       IFNULL(corepapername, 0) AS Core, 
       IFNULL(e1papername, 0) AS Elective1,
       IFNULL(e2papername, 0) AS Elective2
       FROM (
           SELECT student.univ_roll AS roll, student.name AS name, student.rollno AS rollno, 
           (CASE WHEN student.compulsory = paper.subject
             THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS cpapername,
           (CASE WHEN student.core= paper.subject
             THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS corepapername,
           (CASE WHEN student.elective_I= paper.subject
             THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS e1papername,
           (CASE WHEN student.elective_II= paper.subject
             THEN (paper.paper_name) END) AS e2papername
            FROM student, paper WHERE student.semester='First' 
            AND student.batch='2014' AND student.class='BSc' 
            AND student.semester=paper.semester AND student.batch=paper.batch 
            AND student.class=paper.class  AND student.regd='1'
    ) r
```

Comment: what about group_concat? I don't know much about its theory.

Comment: You have both 'as' and 'AS' in your version.  I would consider 'AS' to be more consistent with the other keywords.  You also write 'ifnull' instead of 'IFNULL'.

Comment: ... the standard recommendation now is to not use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), but to explicitly spell out joins.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse that's a very good point. I suggest to post an answer with that!